# Pandas giving me the wrong max date in a date time column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a date column:

```
data['Date']

0        1/1/14
1        1/8/14
2       1/15/14
3       1/22/14
4       1/29/14
         ...   
255    11/21/18
256    11/28/18
257     12/5/18
258    12/12/18
259    12/19/18
```

But, when I try to get the max date out of that column, I get:

```
test_data.Date.max()

'9/9/15'
```

Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Can you check the data type of "date" column ? It may have been a string / object type where something starting with 9 would be the last item when sorted. Converting the date explicitly to a datetime format should help.

Comment: Because it thinks those values are strings and orders them alphanumerically, where 9 is the highest value. Cast your column to date type first, and you are all set.

Comment: That indeed the issue - should have caught it on my own :-(

Comment: I'm voting to close this under the "typo/can't be reproduced" category, since this is simply a matter of a column having the wrong data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly the column is of type `object`. You should try using `pd.to_datetime()` and then performing the `max()` aggregator:

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'],errors='coerce') #You might need to pass format
print(data['Date'].max())
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.max()` understands it as a date (like you want), if it is a [datetime object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html). Building upon [Seshadri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2755985/seshadri)'s response, try:

```
type(data['Date'][1])
```

If it is a datetime object, this returns this:

```
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

If not, you can make that column a datatime object like so:

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'],format='%m/%d/%y')
```

The format argument makes sure you get the right formatting. See the full list of formatting options [here in the python docs](https://strftime.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Your date may be stored as a string. First convert the column from string to datetime. Then, max() should work.

```
test = pd.DataFrame(['1/1/2010', '2/1/2011', '3/4/2020'], columns=['Dates'])

      Dates
0  1/1/2010
1  2/1/2011
2  3/4/2020

pd.to_datetime(test['Dates'], format='%m/%d/%Y').max()
Timestamp('2020-03-04 00:00:00')
```

That timestamp can be cleaned up using .dt.date:

```
pd.to_datetime(test['Dates'], format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.date.max()
datetime.date(2020, 3, 4)
```

to_datetime format argument table [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)
pandas to_datetime [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)